# Sort merged cells with VBA in Excel

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2013

Is there a VBA code that can help me to sort the whole column B with the merged cells?

If sort is equal to name1, I only want to see the name1 and all the data within the rows.

```
|--------------------------------------|
|Header 1| header 2| header 3| header 4|
|--------|---------|---------|---------|
|        | Sort    |         |         |  
|--------------------------------------|
|        |         |  data1  |  data1  |
|id1     | name1   |  data2  |  data2  |
|        |         |  data3  |  data3  |
|--------------------------------------|
|        |         |  data1  |  data1  |
|id2     | name2   |  data2  |  data2  |
|        |         |  data3  |  data3  |
|--------------------------------------|
|        |         |  data1  |  data1  |
|id1     | name1   |  data2  |  data2  |
|        |         |  data3  |  data3  |
|--------------------------------------|
```

Comment: Yes there are many ways of doing it, but I think you should try having a go first on your own. You are kind of just asking the community to do it all for you.

Comment: I have this Macro recorded  Sub SortList()
    Dim sAddStart As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim lRows As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    sAddStart = Selection.Address
    Set rng = Range("B3").Commodity

Comment: With rng
        lRows = .Rows.Count - 2
        .Cells(2).EntireColumn.Insert
        .Cells(2).Offset(0, -1) = "Temp"
        .Cells(2).Offset(1, -1).FormulaR1C1 = _
          "=+RC[1]&"" ""&ROW()"
        .Cells(1).Offset(2, -1).FormulaR1C1 = _
          "=+R[-1]C[1]&"" ""&ROW()"
        Set rng2 = .Cells(2).Offset(1, -1).Resize(lRows, 1)
        Range(.Cells(4, 0), .Cells(11, 0)).AutoFill _
            Destination:=rng2
        rng2.Copy
        rng2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues

Comment: .Columns(2).MergeCells = False

    .CurrentRegion.Sort _
        Key1:=Range("B3"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
        Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, _
        MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

        rng2.EntireColumn.Delete

        With Range(.Cells(4, 1), .Cells(11, 1))
            .Merge
            .Copy
            .Cells(3, 1).Resize(lRows - 2, 1). _
                PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormats
        End With
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range(sAddStart).Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Comment: Maybe you should add that to the question rather than post it in a comment